# Flutter overflow: hidden analogue

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any flutter widget that prevents the children to paint outside a Container by any mean?

I have this container with a child that may get some transformations (such as scale and rotate) and therefore can be painted outside

I want to limit the children's painting to only inside the parent Container, just like a div with CSS `overflow:hidden;` would behave.

A sample:

```
return Container( // the one with overflow hidden -ish behavior
   height: 300.0,
   child: TheTransformingChild() // the one that can get bigger that container
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is - what you're looking for is a combination of [OverflowBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) or [SizedOverflowBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedOverflowBox-class.html) and [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html), or ClipOval, or ClipPath, or ClipRRect etc.

I'd recommend looking through the [painting](https://flutter.io/widgets/painting/) and [layout](https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/) sections of the flutter widget catalog (and the rest of it as well) as it generally does a pretty good job of showcasing the widgets you need.

Comment: Had the same problem with slidable_widget. I have a tabbed navigation and one tab contains a list of slidables (slidable_widget plugin). When they are swiped to one direction they overflow their parent container and caused a glitch on the other tab (they were visible). As a solution I wrapped my TabBarView-Children within a ClipRect, and the glitch was gone. This is the equivalent of z-index and overflow hidden in HTML.

Comment: UseCase: i'm wrap TextInput with border and Icon decoration into Container widget. When i animate setting its height to zero - border and icon drawed outside zero-height Container. ClipRect hide all child content properly. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Instead of `OverflowBox` widget `ClipRect` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 21):

I think it's easier to use clipBehavior: property in container

```
Container(
clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
height: 400,
width: 400,
child :TheTransformingChild(),)
```

Answer (score 13):

An easy way is to use the `Wrap` component (below is your example).

```dart
return Container( // the one with overflow hidden -ish behavior
  height: 300.0,
  child: Wrap(
    children: [
      TheTransformingChild()
    ],
  )
)
```

It also replaces the `Column` component in most cases:

#### Using Column

[image]

#### Using Wrap

[image]